# Using '&&' inside foreach?

Tags: php

I am looking for smart solution, maybe you could help me out. Currently I am doing an own Authentication (Separate Class) system for my Webshop project. My problem is, that I need conditional statement inside foreach loop, to return the code (see below).
 Any suggestions?

My code currently look like this

> ```
> public function regiAuth($email, $password, $firstname, $lastname)
> {
>     $authContainer = [$email, $password, $firstname, $lastname];
>     foreach ($authContainer as $a) {
>         return !empty($_POST[$a]);
>     }
> }
> ```

And I want to result this (With &&)

> return !empty($_POST[$email]) && !empty($_POST[$password]) &&
> !empty($_POST[$firstname]) && !empty($_POST[$lastname])

Comment: What's your question about this? What should that code do? If you use `return` in a loop, only the first element of that array is checked

Comment: If you want to check if all fields are set, wouldn't your code from "_And I want to result this..._" suffice? No need for a `foreach`

Comment: I guess you're confused about `$_POST` use. For example, maybe you mean `$_POST['email']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could do simply by do

```
foreach ($authContainer as $a) {
  if (empty($_POST[$a])
    return false;
}
return true;
```

instead of checking if all of them are full, you look if there is at least one empty.

it is a good practice to stop iteration if you find one element that is not as expected, imagine if you had an array of hundreads of assertions to do.

Answer (score 0):

making an full if statement would look like this, here it checks if the $_POST are not empty. && means that both have to true or false

```
foreach ($authContainer as $a) {
  if((!$_POST[$email]) && (!$_POST[$password])){
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it